# How to solve this error ' converting data type nvarchar to float.' while inserting a record in sql using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql

I am getting error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

while inserting a record into the table using my stored procedure.

My stored procedure is

```
ALTER proc [vipl-user].[SP_Copy_Bill_InsertData]
    (@tablename nvarchar(50)  ,
     @INV_NO nvarchar(50),
     @AC_NO nvarchar(50),
     @AC_NAME nvarchar(255),
     @INV_DATE nvarchar(50),
     @AD1 nvarchar(255),
     @AD2 nvarchar(255),
     @AD3 nvarchar(255),
     @AD4 nvarchar(255),
     @AD5 nvarchar(255),
     @AD6 nvarchar(255),
     @TERMS nvarchar(30),
     @EXCHANGE_RATE float,
     @CREATED_BY nvarchar(10),
     @DATE_CREATED nvarchar(50),
     @ZERO_RATED_INV bit,
     @TAX_INCLUDE bit,
     @Deleted bit,
     @SEAL_NO nvarchar(50),
     @JOB_NO nvarchar(255),
     @Inv_Amt nvarchar(50),
     @GST nvarchar(50),
     @Inv_Net nvarchar(50),
     @Status nvarchar(50)) 
as
begin
    Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

    set @sql = 'insert into '+@tablename+'([INV_NO],[AC_NO],[AC_NAME],[INV_DATE],[AD1],[AD2],[AD3],[AD4],[AD5],[AD6],[TERMS],[EXCHANGE_RATE],[CREATED_BY],[DATE_CREATED],[ZERO_RATED_INV],[TAX_INCLUDE],[Deleted],[SEAL_NO],JOB_NO,Inv_Amt,GST,Inv_Net,Status) values ('''+@INV_NO+''','''+@AC_NO+''','''+@AC_NAME+''','+CAST(@INV_DATE as varchar(50))+','''+@AD1+''','''+@AD2+''','''+@AD3+''','''+@AD4+''','''+@AD5+''','''+@AD6+''','''+@TERMS+''','''+CAST(@EXCHANGE_RATE as float)+''','''+@CREATED_BY+''','+CAST(@DATE_CREATED as varchar(50))+','+CAST(@ZERO_RATED_INV as CHAR(1))+','+CAST(@TAX_INCLUDE as CHAR(1))+','+CAST(@Deleted as CHAR(1))+','''+@SEAL_NO+''','''+@JOB_NO+''','+CAST(@Inv_Amt as decimal)+','+CAST(@GST as decimal)+','+CAST(@Inv_Net as decimal)+','''+@Status+''')'
    exec(@sql)
    end
```

I am doing my project in 3 tier I have taken Exchangerate field in BEL as float/decimal.

Would you please resolve this error.

Comment: Why are you passing in a table name? Can you provide details of the structure of the table (And confirm the name you are passing in is the table it is trying to insert into?

Comment: map your datatype from table and store procedure

Comment: The error might also be because when the dynamic SQL is generated, you are trying to a put a non numeric value (i.e. 'A') into a float field and it doesn't know how to convert it.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If you have parameters that are **dates** - ***USE*** an appropriate type! (`DATE` or `DATETIME`) If you have parameters that are numeric values - again ***use the appropriate*** type! (`DECIMAL` or `INT` or whatever). Don't just use `NVARCHAR` for everything!!

Comment: Even though this is a stored procedure, you are still open to sql injection since you are using concatenation to create your query.

Answer (score 0):

CAST all @variables to `VARCHAR` like this

```
set @sql='insert into '+@tablename+'([INV_NO],[AC_NO],[AC_NAME],[INV_DATE],[AD1],[AD2],[AD3],[AD4],[AD5],[AD6],[TERMS],[EXCHANGE_RATE],[CREATED_BY],[DATE_CREATED],[ZERO_RATED_INV],[TAX_INCLUDE],[Deleted],[SEAL_NO],JOB_NO,Inv_Amt,GST,Inv_Net,Status) values ('''+@INV_NO+''','''+@AC_NO+''','''+@AC_NAME+''','''+CAST(@INV_DATE as varchar(50))+','''+@AD1+''','''+@AD2+''','''+@AD3+''','''+@AD4+''','''+@AD5+''','''+@AD6+''','''+@TERMS+''','''+CAST(@EXCHANGE_RATE as varchar(50)+''','''+@CREATED_BY+''','''+CAST(@DATE_CREATED as varchar(50))+','''+CAST(@ZERO_RATED_INV as varchar(50)+','''+CAST(@TAX_INCLUDE as varchar(50)+','''+CAST(@Deleted as varchar(50)+','''+@SEAL_NO+''','''+@JOB_NO+''','''+CAST(@Inv_Amt as varchar(50)+','''+CAST(@GST as varchar(50)+','''+CAST(@Inv_Net as varchar(50)+','''+@Status+''')'
```

This is because you have DECLARED `@SQL as VARCHAR(MAX)`, so the entire query must be in VARCHAR when `@SQL` is executed in `EXEC(@SQL)`

Comment: Your welcome. And if you feel this answer is correct, just click on the TICK mark.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

I have not included all the columns and provided only 2 cols i.e EXCHANGE_RATE having float and DATE_CREATED having nvarchar(50).You can modify your sp and include all your columns like below approach to execute dynamic sql insert statements.

```
declare @paramDefinition nvarchar(max)

set @sql = 'insert into 
    '+@tablename+' ([EXCHANGE_RATE],[DATE_CREATED]) 
    values (@EXCHANGE_RATE,@DATE_CREATED)'

SET @paramDefinition = N'@tablename nvarchar(max),@EXCHANGE_RATE float,@DATE_CREATED nvarchar(50)'

EXECUTE sp_executesql  @sql,@paramDefinition,@tablename,@EXCHANGE_RATE,@CREATED_BY
```

In this way , you don't need to cast each input parameter to varchar in the dynamic sql insert query and can use most appropriate datatype while inserting.

Comment: Yes In this way also we can do it